# What is the tailhook on naval aircraft made out of?

Tags: military, aircraft-carrier, aerospace-materials, arrestor-hook

What is the tailhook that enable naval aircraft to land on aircraft carriers, it must be made out of a strong metal to not bend or 'snap' under the force of the thrust that the plane is expelling, as they land then put thrust to full.

[image]

<sup>[Image Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Navy_111222-N-DR144-395_Landing_signal_officers_supervise_the_arrested_recovery_of_an_F-A-18C_Hornet_on_the_flight_deck_aboard_the_Nimitz-class.jpg)—PACIFIC OCEAN (Dec. 22, 2011) Landing signal officers supervise the arrested recovery of an F/A-18C Hornet on the flight deck aboard the Nimitz-class aircraft carrier USS Carl Vinson (CVN 70).</sup>

Comment: Looking at the specs, it is steel. Looking at the price, it must be unobtainium.

Comment: You may also refer the [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Navy_111222-N-DR144-395_Landing_signal_officers_supervise_the_arrested_recovery_of_an_F-A-18C_Hornet_on_the_flight_deck_aboard_the_Nimitz-class.jpg) image, there is a description with it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're made of alloy steels that have **ultra-high strength,** high [fracture toughness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_toughness), excellent fatigue resistance, and high resistance to stress corrosion cracking.

Based on one of the manufacturers—[QuesTek](http://www.questek.com/ferrium-m54.html)—the [steel's grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_steel_grades) is AMS 6516.

The 6xxx grade is a [chromium-vanadium steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium-vanadium_steel):

> **Chromium-vanadium steel** refers to steel alloys incorporating carbon, manganese, phosphorus, sulfur, silicon, chromium, and vanadium. Some forms can be used as high-speed steel. Chromium and vanadium both make the steel more hardenable. Chromium also helps resist abrasion, oxidation, and corrosion. Chromium and carbon can both improve **elasticity.**

Elasticity is important because you wouldn't want a [deformable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(engineering)) tailhook.

Other applications for it are:

> Landing gear, rotorshafts, driveshafts, arresting tailhooks and hookshanks, actuators, armor, munitions, gun barrels, and blast-resistant or impact containment devices.